# how to make post request in python with application/x-www-form-urlencoded for raw data post

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, http-headers, postman

I try make post request to server and get the reply in postman. Its work fine. But when i try this in python, server send "invalid client" as a reply.In the postman, this thing work fine. here is my python code

```
import mysql.connector
import requests
import json
import urllib3
import time

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    password = "",
    database = "python-db"
)


mycursor = mydb.cursor()
url = "https://example.com/oauth2/token"
header = {
    
    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Content-Length":"121",
    "Host":"example.com",
    "Connection":"Keep-Alive",
    "Accept-Encoding":"gzip",
    "User-Agent":"okhttp/3.11.0"
    }
payload = {b"scope=scope1&password=123&client_id=789&username=951&grant_type=password"}
response = requests.post(url, data=(payload), headers=header, verify=False)
r_json = response.json()
print(r_json)
```

I try this in postman with those headers and data, its work fine. In postman payload data type is raw. What is the error and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 4):

```
payload ="scope=scope1&password=123&client_id=789&username=951&grant_type=password"
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=header, verify=False)
```

Comment: Thank you very much its on the () bracket case